# Can law enforcement officer solicit complaints? Can you cite case/code?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

Living in a Home Owners Association for fifteen years. Not a good experience. I was cited for dog at large and a complaint was signed by a neighbor. Police note states "I will have day shift patrol contact the RP, and see how they would like to continue." Can those officers go back and solicit complaints?

Comment: Is there some reason you think they would not be able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

### Absolutely

Asking questions is 90% of how police conduct investigations.

In fact, where I live [australia](/questions/tagged/australia) there’s a whole [website](https://crimestoppers.com.au) and phone service specifically for soliciting complaints.

Comment: Providing a communication method (web site) to take citizen complaints is not the same thing as soliciting a complaint.